# Should the spacing between the star number indicator and the question star itself be increased?

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface, bookmarks

On the TeX SE, the number of stars a question has received seems to overlap the star.

It isn't really an issue with single-digit numbers, which seem to fit neatly into the crevasse between the two bottom points.

[image: 2 stars]

However, multi-digit numbers are too long to avoid running into the star.

[image: 221 stars]

Should something be done about this? The overlap itself isn't really screaming for attention; the conspicuous part is more the lack of space in comparison to the nearby upvote/downvote buttons and the question stars of the other SEs. My main concern is that this sense of "crushed" interface elements makes the site look a little less polished than it could.

Comparison to [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com):

[image]

Comment: Excellent edit, @Werner. Thank you!

Comment: related: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3374/rendering-issues-due-to-overlapping-fields

Comment: Starred, to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 5):

The fixing of [a bug related to the spacing](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4274/the-favorite-count-makes-part-of-the-star-unclickable?lq=1) involved un-smashing the number:

> [image]

This is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), and the fact that there was a bug indicates that yes, it should be (has been) increased.