# The favorite count makes part of the star unclickable

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, bookmarks

I was idly browsing through TeX.SE, and at one point attempted to favourite ("star") a question that had already been starred more than a hundred times. Nothing happened. I tapped (yeah, touchscreen) higher on the icon, at which point the expected result occurred.

Further investigation revealed that the star count being sandwiched up into the icon ([as reported here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4206/35325)) causes it to overlap the star's clickable box in the page DOM; and as the count is the later DOM element, it prevents the lower part of the star being clickable.

> [image] [image] [image]
>   The blue boxes are the overlapped areas. Pretty bad, isn't it?

The culprit is a single CSS property

```
.favoritecount { margin-top: -4px; }
```

with the effect of smashing the number into the star. Make that less negative and the problem goes away.

Comment: Impossible.... You can't idly browse TeX-SX. I propose closing :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have pushed a fix to dev. The change will go live after our next production build(within 24 hours)

Comment: Jin is our hero! :)

Comment: @tohecz: Am I too old if I confess I thought of Earthworm Jim when I read your comment? `:)`

Comment: Sorry to bother you Jin, but have you seen http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3824/can-the-box-made-by-the-kbd-html-tag-be-made-smaller?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I'm going through the bug list now. I'll fix that today.

Comment: 49 hours and no production build yet - could someone be poked with a sharp stick?

Comment: @michaelb958 I forgot I made the fix on Friday. we don't make production builds as frequently on the weekends. There definitely will be a build tomorrow.

Comment: @Jin A build has been performed; accepting this answer.